Why $A+B\subseteq A+C$ implies $B\subseteq C$ when $A$ is bounded and $C$ is closed and convex in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
I am having difficulty proving the following assertion:
$A+B \subseteq A+C$ implies $B \subseteq C$ , when $A$ is bounded and $C$ is closed and convex in $\mathbb{R}^n$
For this to make sense, $A$ , $B$ , and $C$ are supposed to be non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. $B$ is otherwise arbitrary but $A$ is supposed to be bounded, while $C$ is supposed to be closed and convex.
I can see that the assumption of $A$ being bounded is necessary, otherwise there is a simple counterexample with $A$ being a straight vertical line, $C$ a closed disk disjoint with $A$, and $B$ a single point outside the disk but right above its center.
As far as proving $B \subseteq C$ , I was thinking of considering first the case when $A$ is finite, and then for the infinite case, coming up with some convergent sequence in $C$ but my ideas are very vague and I am clueless about how to use the convexity of $C$.
Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Welcome to Math Stack Ex ! Where was the Exercise given ?

Thank you, Prem. The exercise was given in a Mathematical Analysis course. The professor said he took it from a book but he did not remembered which one.

It is sufficient to prove the result with $B=\{b\}$. If we let $C'=C-\{b\}$, then we wish to prove that $A \subset A + C'$ implies $0 \in C'$
Suppose $0 \notin C'$ and let $\lambda$ be a functional strictly separating $0$ from $C'$, that is, there is some $\alpha >0$ such that $\alpha \le \lambda(c)$ for all $c \in C'$
Suppose $a_k \in A$, then there are $a_{k+1} \in A, c_{k+1} \in C'$ such that $a_k = a_{k+1}+c_{k+1}$, or equivalently $a_k - a_{k+1}=c_{k+1}$ Summing gives
$a_1 - a_n = c_2+...+c_n$ and applying $\lambda$ to both sides gives
$\lambda(a_1-a_n) \ge (n-1) \alpha$. However, since $A$ is bounded we see that this gives a contradiction.
Hence $0 \in C'$, or equivalently, $b \in C$.

where is convexity argument used exactly ? (because else for $A=C=\text{cantor set}$ and $B={\frac 12}$ then $A+C=[0,2]$ but $\frac 12\notin C$).

@zwim Using Hahn Banach to obtain $\lambda$.
